# MongoDB - How to select one product in each category?

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections - "products" and "categories".
Each product has "category_id" attribute.

I need to select last 30 products, and these products should be in different categories.

categories

```
{
    _id: 'books',
    name: 'Books',
},
{
    _id: 'computers',
    name: 'Computers',
}
```

products

```
{
    name: 'The Lean Startup',
    category_id: 'books',
    created: ISODate("2013-05-29T10:37:58.071Z")
},
{
    name: 'Start Small, Stay Small',
    category_id: 'books',
    created: ISODate("2013-05-29T10:37:58.071Z")
}
```

Comment: your question is not clear. Give sample data.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the aggregation framework for your task. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/

Your query would involve

- `$sort` by `created`
- `$group` by `category_id`
- and probably `$limit`

Comment: I did try this. It returns list of category_id.  So in this case I need two queries. May be there is way to do this with one query.

Comment: Take a look at this post about implementing joins using Map-Reduce http://blog.knoldus.com/2013/02/03/joins-now-possible-in-mongodb/